# Grid css issues

Tags: asp.net, css

i had a gridview in my report but my grid css is distorting if i set min height and width but i want to set becuse want to automaticaly adjust gridview according to my main div ie the grid should be accordingly streched according to main div or screen and data cells are also merging due to this so waht should i do

```
<div class="dvmain">


<table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
  <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto;min-height:500px;">                                             
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" width:auto Height:auto 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True"  CssClass="Itemgrid"
          RowStyle-CssClass="RowStyle" 
  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">

                         <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itdsrno" HeaderText="Srno" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itemname" HeaderText="Item" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itdlength" HeaderText="Gsm" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltotalquan" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                         </FooterTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblquantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itdquan") 

%>'></asp:Label>
                         </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="unitname" HeaderText="Nos" />
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="mstexcDes" HeaderText="Grain" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">

                            <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="INR"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# 

String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"itdRate")) %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbltxttotal" runat="server"  />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="server" Text='<%# 

String.Format("{0:f2}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"itdAmou")) %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="itdrema" HeaderText="Remark" />
                    </Columns>


                </asp:GridView>
</div>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>





</div>
```

css

```
<style type="text/css">
     .style1
  { 
    min-width:200px;

  }
        div.title
        {


            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:14px;

         }
        .style2
        {
        }
        .dvitems
        {
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:12px;
            width: 108px;
        }
        .dvpo
        {
             font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:12px;
            width: 70px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .dvinstruction
        {
             font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:12px;
            margin-left:20px;
        }
         .dvterms
         {
             font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:12px;
            margin-left:10px;
         }

        .style4
        {           
           height: 18px;
        }

        .style6
        {
        }
        div.dvmain
        {

        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;
        margin-left:80px;
        margin-top:50px;
        width:80%
        min-height:650px;
        font-family:Verdana;

        }
        .grd
        {
            font-family:Verdana;
            min-height:400px;
             position:relative;

        }
        .grd td
        {
           text-align:center;
           border: solid 1px #000000; 


        }


       /* div.dvtitle
        {
          border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;  
        }*/
         div.dvright
        {
         /* border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000; */ 
        }
         div.dvleft
        {
          border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000000;  
        }
      .tbborder 
      {
          border:1px solid black;
         border-right-style:none;
         border-left-style:none;

      }
      table.tbpayterms
      {
          border-left-style:none;
          border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
          border-spacing: 0;
          border-style: solid;

      }
      .tbpayterms td
        {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
        }


        .body
        {
            font-family:Verdana;
        }

        .verticalLine {
            border-right:thick solid #000000;
            height:auto;
            border-width:1px;

            }

        .dvfaith
        {
            width: 138px;
        }

        .dvthanks
        {
            width: 117px;
        }




        .style14
        {
            width: 319px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .style15
        {
            height: 22px;
        }


        .style17
        {
            width: 159px;
        }




        .style39
        {
            width: 219px;
        }




        .style40
        {
            width: 103px;
        }
        .style41
        {
            width: 102px;
        }
        .style42
        {
            width: 249px;
        }
        .style43
        {
            width: 185px;
        }




        .style58
        {
        }
        .style61
        {
            width: 69px;
        }




        .style63
        {
            width: 340px;
        }
        .style64
        {
            width: 273px;
        }




        .style67
        {
            width: 73px;
        }
        .style68
        {
            width: 87px;
        }




        .style69
        {
            width: 528px;
        }




        .style70
        {
            width: 112px;
        }
        @media print {
input#btnPrint {
display: none;
}
input#btnback {
display: none;
}

}



    </style>
```

Comment: Consider removing unnecessary details...